# complex projection from many-to-many tables, DbContext and entity framework and Linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have a DbContext with these four *many-to-many* related entities:

```
Classes <-> Students
Classes <-> Assignments
Classes <-> Contents
Classes <-> Announcements
```

Now I need a Linq code (or sth. better!) which will give us **last 3 Assignments**, **last 3 Contents**, **last 3 Announcements** of each Class where the student with StudentId = X is in those classes.

In another hand, the student logged in to website and we wanna show him/her last Assignments, Contents, Announcements of each Classes which he/she is study in it.

this code is not correct but may help u understand my need. Also this code takes many times to run (50ms isn't many?):

**Edit:** Code was almost correct so moved to answer , look at accepted answer. Any other (better, faster) solutions appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The difference with my code is that you've only got a `SelectMany` on classes. My code has more `SelectMany`'s. I think your code is better. So have you still got issues now? Otherwise you could put your code in an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @**Gert Arnold** recommendation I had changed a little my code:

- start the query with student
- narrow down the result by changing selected properties

```cs
db.Students.Where(st => st.StudentId.Equals(CurrentUser)).SelectMany(S => S.Classes, (S, C) => new
{
    Name = C.Name,
    Assignments = C.Assignments.Select(AS => new { AS.Id, AS.Name }).OrderByDescending(As => As.Id).Take(3),
    Contents = C.Contents.Select(Co => new { Co.Id, Co.Title }).OrderByDescending(Co => Co.Id).Take(3),
    Announcements = C.Announcements.Select(An => new { An.Id, An.Title }).OrderByDescending(An => An.Id).Take(3)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You better start the query with student:

```
from s in db.Students
where s.StudentId == CurrentUser
from c in s.Classes
from as in c.Assignments.OrderByDescending(As => As.Id).Take(3)
from co in c.Contents.OrderByDescending(Co => Co.Id).Take(3)
from an in c.Announcements.OrderByDescending(An => An.Id).Take(3)
select new { <selected properties> }
```

The last part (selected properties) is important. By selecting only a subset of properties you narrow down the result set from the database. Without this, you create a very wide and long result set because of the large number of joins in the (SQL) query.

Comment: thank you dude for your nice advice, I'm waiting maybe someone else has better answer(Faster).Another question: My new code  works but consumes times (50ms in my PC as EntityFrameworkProfiler), Is it possible be there problems if 1000 students at the same time request this page? Also EntityFrameworkProfiler warn me _Avoid too many joins_. Any faster way? [link](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/EFProf/learn/alert/TooManyJoins).